# R plot 2 axes multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, axes

I'm trying to produce a very specific graphical output, and can't find a package that can do all of the things I'm looking for. Primarily, I need to:
(1) Produce multiple plots (facet_wrap in ggplot works great)
(2) Have 2 y-axes with different scales (lattice seems the best for this)
(3) Produce a graph similar to the output from "plot" using dplR

I have a data frame with multiple unique Sites. I'd like to plot each site's average annual value as a line graph, with a second line graph on the other y-axis representing sample depth. I'd like to produce a separate plot for each site.

Below is some reproducible data(small subset), and what I've come up with so far:

```
> sites <- structure(list(Year = c("2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", 
"2012"), plot = c("FA6", "FA7", "FK1", "FK2", "FK3", "FO1", "FO2", 
"FO6", "GA2", "GA4", "GR1", "GR2", "HE2", "HE3", "LY1", "LY3", 
"LY8", "NM2", "NM3", "TH3", "TH5", "BR1", "BR8", "FA5", "FA6", 
"FA7", "FK1", "FK2", "FK3", "FO1", "FO2", "FO6", "GA2", "GA4", 
"GR1", "GR2", "HE2", "HE3", "LY1", "LY3", "LY8", "NM2", "NM3", 
"TH3", "TH5", "FA5", "FA6", "FA7", "FK1", "FK2", "FK3", "FO1", 
"FO2", "FO6", "GA2", "GA4", "GR1", "GR2", "HE2", "HE3", "LY1", 
"LY3", "LY8", "NM2", "NM3", "TH3", "TH5", "HE2", "HE3", "TH5"
), AvgRW = c(0.628666666666667, 0.485027777777778, 0.479269230769231, 
0.826875, 0.633269230769231, 1.01830769230769, 1.34580555555556, 
1.13061764705882, 0.422375, 1.377625, 0.535375, 0.366384615384615, 
0.493119047619048, 0.300777777777778, 0.971923076923077, 1.02302941176471, 
1.47245833333333, 1.00654166666667, 0.56425, 1.66342857142857, 
1.28477586206897, 0.860666666666667, 2.10155130769231, 1.74626923076923, 
0.616148148148148, 0.42775, 0.402576923076923, 0.859333333333333, 
0.608961538461538, 1.28303846153846, 1.84344444444444, 1.52214705882353, 
0.425546875, 1.66179166666667, 0.647208333333333, 0.390461538461538, 
0.565892857142857, 0.237388888888889, 1.60419230769231, 1.16611764705882, 
1.95329166666667, 1.18795833333333, 0.655928571428571, 2.009, 
1.36198275862069, 2.61165384615385, 0.873296296296296, 0.596, 
0.485884615384615, 1.13633333333333, 0.684461538461538, 1.30946153846154, 
1.69747222222222, 1.64197058823529, 0.40740625, 1.40716666666667, 
0.641625, 0.428576923076923, 0.729011904761905, 0.376222222222222, 
1.52984615384615, 1.15317647058824, 1.66183333333333, 1.17904166666667, 
0.604857142857143, 1.57425, 1.55772222222222, 0.7315, 0.119, 
1.125875), SampDepth = c(27L, 18L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 17L, 
32L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 29L, 
21L, 13L, 13L, 27L, 18L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 17L, 32L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 13L, 17L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 29L, 13L, 27L, 
18L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 17L, 32L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 
13L, 17L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 8L)), .Names = c("Year", 
"plot", "AvgRW", "SampDepth"), row.names = 2330:2399, class = "data.frame")
```

I can get a great layout using ggplot and ggplus, but can't seem to add second y-axis:

```
Plot1 <- ggplot(sites,aes(x=Year, y=AvgRW, group=plot)) + 
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=4), 
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.major=element_line(colour = "gray",size=0.5), 
          strip.text=element_text(size=8)) + 
    geom_line()

facet_multiple(plot = Plot1, facets = 'plot', ncol = 1, nrow = 1, scales="free")
```

[image: Sample graph]

Then I tried doing a doubleYplot with lattice and latticeExtra, but I can't get the lines to appear:

```
Plot2a <- xyplot(AvgRW ~ Year, data=sites, groups=plot,
              xlab=list("Year", fontsize = 12),
              ylab = list("Avg RW (mm)", fontsize = 12),
              ylab.right = list("Sample Depth", fontsize = 12),
              par.settings = simpleTheme(col = 1),
              type = c("l","g"),
              lty=1,
              scales=list(x=list(rot=90,tick.number=25,
                                 cex=1,axs="r")))

> Plot2b <- xyplot(SampDepth ~ Year,data=sites, groups=plot, type = "o",col="black",
              lty=9)

> doubleYScale(Plot2a, Plot2b)
```

My ultimate goal is to produce a graph that looks similar to the dplR output, for every site in my data.frame:

[image: Intended output]

Any ideas on how to combine my three goals would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, you can have [two y-axes](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2) labels in GGplot

Comment: Thanks. I know ggplot can do 2 axis labels, but I don't know how to graph 2 lines with the same x axis but different y values.

Comment: The link in my comment illustrates how to have the same scale on the x-axis and separate scales on the left and right y-axes.  The use of `ncol = 1, nrow = 1, scales="free"` produces one figure per slide, which could be accomplished via `pdf(blah,blah,blah); for(p in unique(sites$plot) show(Plot1 %+% sites[sites$plot == p]); dev.off()`.   If you're trying to add a second line on the same y-scale, use `Plot1 + geom_smooth(blah,blah,blah)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the link and applied the code to my own data, however it's producing all plots on 1 graph. I tried adding the for loop in, but loops aren't my specialty: I can't get the loop to run correctly. If you could help me figure out how to apply the loop, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` does not support a secondary y-axis because his creator believe that it can be misleading. However, you can do it with `base` R. Here's a loop that solves your problems: multiple plots in a loop, secondary y-axis, similar look to the attached plot. I assumed that you are on Windows and included the code to save every chart in your /temp directory using savePlot.

```
for (i in sites$plot){                          #start loop
par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,5.1))                     #increase right margin
plot(sites[sites$plot==i,c(1,3)],xaxt="n", type="l", ylab="Avg RW")
title(main=i,line=2.5)                              #add title
axis(1,at=as.integer(sites$Year),labels=sites$Year) #bottom axis
axis(3,at=as.integer(sites$Year),labels=sites$Year) #top axis
par(new = TRUE)                                     #overlay for secondary y
plot(sites[sites$plot==i,c(1,4)],xaxt="n",yaxt="n", ylab="",type="l", col="red")
axis(4)                                             #add secondary y axis
mtext("Sample Depth", side = 4, line=2)             #add secondary y label
savePlot(filename = paste0("c:/temp/",i, ".png"), type = "png") # save
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE** If you are not on Windows, you cannot use `savePlot`. Use the normal `png` function. You will not see the charts on screen but they will be saved. Make sure to change the path to where you want the charts saved. I am using `c:/temp/` in the following code, which will not work on non-windows machines.

```
for (i in sites$plot){                          #start loop
png(filename = paste0("c:/temp/",i, ".png")) # save
par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,5.1))                     #increase right margin
plot(sites[sites$plot==i,c(1,3)],xaxt="n", type="l", ylab="Avg RW")
title(main=i,line=2.5)                              #add title
axis(1,at=as.integer(sites$Year),labels=sites$Year) #bottom axis
axis(3,at=as.integer(sites$Year),labels=sites$Year) #top axis
par(new = TRUE)                                     #overlay for secondary y
plot(sites[sites$plot==i,c(1,4)],xaxt="n",yaxt="n", ylab="",type="l", col="red")
axis(4)                                             #add secondary y axis
mtext("Sample Depth", side = 4, line=2)             #add secondary y label
dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great; the output graph is just what I was looking for. The only issue I had was the actual loop: when I ran it in R, only the first plot from the data.frame was graphed. I couldn't locate any of the other graphs. I applied it both to the subsetted data.frame I used above, and also to my own full data.frame, and in both cases I could only get the last graph to appear. Any ideas?

Comment: I should also add that I'm getting this error message: "Error in savePlot(filename = paste0("c:/temp/", i, ".png"), type = "png") : 
  can only copy from 'windows' devices"

Comment: Yes, I wrote that I assumed that you were on Windows in my original answer. I added an update, which will work on non-windows machines. Make sure to change the path to where you want the charts saved (should not be c:/temp/)

Comment: By the way, you could only see the first chart because of the savePlot error. The loop stops when it encounters an error.

Comment: The fix worked great! I had to change ".png" to type="png" and then it ran exactly as needed!